# How to generate unit test case code coverage report in .pdf for all components using angular9 and Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular9, karma-coverage, angular-unit-test

Angular support code coverage report in .html format(Index.html). The same code coverage report can it be possible to get in .pdf version using angular 9/Jasmine?

I had tried to modified some settings in Karma.config.js file but no luck. Is any plugin  available for it? "Karma-jasmine-html-reporter" same for .pdf file?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Maybe there is a way to convert HTML to PDF. Perhaps you can use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-node

Answer (score 0):

[How to write unit test cases automatically using SCURI in angular 8 onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667395/how-to-write-unit-test-cases-automatically-using-scuri-in-angular-8-onwards)

run "ng test" to see coverage report for these unit tests