# How to write unit test cases automatically using SCURI in angular 8 onwards

Tags: angular, unit-testing, automated-tests

There is an npm package named SCURI which can be utilized to write unit test cases for .ts files automatically to cover more than 70% coverage .

Just need to install this package and once done, create autoSpy.ts file to define how to mock/create stubs for dependencies.
[image]

Comment: What makes you think that testing can be specified automatically? I know several deservedly well-paid people in testing who might be offended by the idea. In that context I really do not see what your question might be, the title is not enough and the body does not elaborate on what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

As it stated in the docs, it

> Automates unit test boilerplate for Angular

so, reduces the no-brainers, i.e spec file creation, imports, constructor instantiations, method invocations, basic AAA pattern, some mocking etc.

All the (advanced) logical design and checks you better do yourself.

Comment: IMHO is not even close to claimed 70%. As the thought process is the main ingredient in testing, no? :)

Answer (score 1):

author of Scuri here.

So nice to see a discussion of my work.

Thanks Azure-Techno for starting this thread and ekostadinov and Shabeer M as well for your words.

And yes - it "only" does the mundane and repetitive work. It won't do the heavy-lift thought process - can't really. (Maybe chatGPq might?)

Anyway - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the SCURI pluggin only will generate spec for you and help you update it when dependencies are added or removed!

Comment: correct for all public methods only, but still a good help for beginner

Comment: Also you would only l;eft with your assert statements and logic in between, mocking ur dependencies, and stubs for all functions in your file, it will do for you.